# Accordion menus for ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, menu

Are there any plugins for this? Otherwise what free accordion code would you all recommend for a rails site? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This would fall under the realm of view code. Feel free to implement any solution you would normally use with HTML. The Rails community seems to prefer jQuery and Prototype so I would take a look at

- [jQuery Accordion](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Accordion)
- [Accordion v2.0](http://www.p51labs.com/accordion/)